# Java change input to uppercase using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, uppercase

Hi I have issue with changing my input to uppercase using recursion. This is my homework and the instruction said I'm not allowed to use toUpperCase() and/or isUpperCase() method.

I have tried using loop and it worked.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class hw5 {

    static void convertCase(String str) {

        int[] asciiArray = new int[str.length()];
        char[] charArray = new char[asciiArray.length];
        int ascii = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { 
            char character = str.charAt(i); 
            ascii = (int) character;
            //change the value if lower case
            if(ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122) {
                asciiArray[i] = ascii-32;
                charArray[i] = (char) asciiArray[i];
            }
            //don't change the value if the value is already uppercase or 0-9 (I think this is the base case)
            else if((ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90) || (ascii >= 48 && ascii <= 57))  {
                asciiArray[i] = ascii;
                charArray[i] = (char) asciiArray[i];
            }
            System.out.print(charArray[i]);
         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        convertCase("uPPerCAse123");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
UPPERCASE123
```

How to write those using recursion?

Comment: Can you provide us with the recursive method that you've worked so far?

Comment: Strange request. Recursion is not a good choice for this homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that we could introduce recursion into your current logic would be to replace the iterative `for` loop with recursive calls:

```
public static void convertCase(String str) {
    convertCase(str, 0, str.length()-1);
}

private static void convertCase(String input, int start, int end) {
    if (input == null || start > end) {
        return;
    }
    char character = input.charAt(start); 
    int ascii = (int) character;
    if (ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122) {
        character = (char)(ascii-32);
    }
    System.out.print(character);        
    convertCase(input, start+1, end);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    convertCase("all lowercase HERE");
}
```

This prints:

```
ALL LOWERCASE HERE
```

Each recursive call prints one letter of the string, using a `start` input pointer. Then, it makes a recursive call, incrementing that start pointer by one, to recursively work its way down the input string.

Comment: That's so fast! how to aquire this level of recursion thinking? it helps me a lot. It's only a little part of my homework actually, but I can tweak it from here. Thanks Tim.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Well we might more likely expect to use recursion in a divide and conquer algorithm, such as merge sort.  I wouldn't use recursion for this problem, actually, iteration is just fine. I only give this suggested answer as one possible to introduce recursion.

Answer (score 3):

```
public String stringToUpperCase(String str){
    if (str.length==1) return charToUpperCase((char)str[0]);
    return charToUpperCase((char)str[0]) + stringToUpperCase(str.substring(1,str.length-1));



public Char charToUpperCase(Char char){
    int ascii = (int)char;
    if (ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122) {
        ascii -= 32;
    }
    return (Char)ascii;
}


public static void(String... args){
    System.out.println(stringToUpperCase("asdf");
}
```

In this version stringToUpperCase() explicitly calls itself, which is the key of recursion.

Comment: This logic works too. It's interesting that I could use multiple ways to fulfill this. I'll try using my own logic based on the answers here. Thanks

Comment: Déjà vu.... and wouldn't it be better to use `'a'` instead of 97? And why convert to `int`, `char` is already an integral value?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args){
    String word ="sathira";
    convertUpper(word,word.length());
  }

   static void convertUpper(String word,int length){

      if (word==null||length ==0)
        return;
   char character = word.charAt(length-1); 
    int ascii = (int) character;
    if (ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122) {
        character = (char)(ascii-32);
    }
     convertUpper(word,length-1);
    System.out.print(character);        

  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here my version of to upper case for one character (only ASCII, not tested):

```
char static toUpper(char ch) {
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
        ch += 'A' - 'a';
    }
    return ch;
}
```

or, converted to conditional operator:

```
ch = (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') ? (char) (ch + 'A' - 'a') : ch;
```

these can easily be inserted in any of the other recursive solutions already presented in the other answers (not sure which one I prefer, it's *strange* to have that done in a recursive way)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive implementation in Java. It is based on head recursion -

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String []args){
    String changed = toUpperCaseRec("sTr12uv3X");
    System.out.println(changed);
}

static String toUpperCaseRec(String str) {
    if(str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    String rem = toUpperCaseRec(str.substring(1));
    Character cc = convertToUppercase(str.charAt(0));
    return cc+rem;
}

static Character convertToUppercase(Character chr) {
    if(chr >= 97 && chr <= 122) {
        return (char)(chr - 32);
    } else {
        return chr;
    }
}
```

}